# Would asking about the feeling of British natives toward the widespread of American English on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions

I just wonder what British natives feel when they see American English is being used globally (?). English originated in Britain, but now British have to see everyone using American spelling and pronunciations.

Is that question on-topic?

Comment: The language spoken in America is just as old and just as original as the one spoken by native speakers elsewhere.

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен♦ How is asking whether a question would be ontopic on the main site an off topic question for meta?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Feelings are primarily opinion based

Comment: This is news to me...that AmE is spoken everywhere.  I thought I was in the minority.  What about Australia, India, New Zeland, Canada, South Africa, and of course the UK?

Comment: @michael_timofeev sooo, can I ask what's your feeling?

Comment: I'm not sure I see AmE taking over or being the predominant choice.  I think the reason one might feel this way is because of the Hollywood marketing machine...so it seems AmE is the global version.  To me it seems pointless to compare or say the because English "originated" in England it is better or the true source.  Language evolves.  We have our way of expressing ourselves and in the UK they have many ways.  Also, I think it is dubious to say that American spelling  or pronunciation is everywhere.  American pronunciation is not what I hear when talking to colleagues in India.

Comment: It would be no different, in effect, from asking (on the main site): *"@Ooker often makes grammar mistakes in his questions. How do you guys feel when you see this?"* It's not appropriate (whether or not it is true is irrelevant to the point), it's not about understanding and exploring a language, and it's not productive.

Comment: @michael_timofeev of course American pronunciation is not what you hear in India, but the grammar and writing spelling (*meter* vs *metre*) issues still exist.

Comment: @medica I see XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primarily because it is a question of human reaction, rather than one of syntax or language subtleties, it would probably not be considered on-topic.